# Serverless Framework - S3 upload lambda trigger

Tags: amazon-s3, server, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'd like to trigger different lambdas on the same bucket according to the folder where the file is uploaded. Basically, when the user uploads a file to "user/some_id/bills" I want to trigger lambda 1; When the user upload a file to "user/some_id/docs" I want to trigger lambda 2;

I tried the configuration bellow but did not work...

```
insertUploadBill:
handler: resources/insertUploadBill.main
events:
  - s3:
      bucket: ${self:custom.settings.BUCKET}
      event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
      rules:
        - prefix: user/*/bills/       

insertUploadDocs:
handler: resources/insertUploadDoc.main
events:
  - s3:
      bucket: ${self:custom.settings.BUCKET}
      event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
      rules:
        - prefix: user/*/docs/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at the docs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-filtering

The wild card characters in rules (prefix / suffix) cannot be used.

1. So either you can change the S3 object key to match something like this
   `user/images/[user-id]`
2. Or you can make a separate lambda to be invoked on all the `s3:ObjectCreated:*` events and then use this lambda to match the key and invoke your current lambdas. `resources/insertUploadBill.main` and `resources/insertUploadDoc.main`

Comment: I ended up using the second approach. Tks